After upgrading to 24.04 changing the keyboard layout in Settings has no effect
At the top right the correct icon (for me "it2") appears, but the keyboard does not change.
The following may help a more knowledgeable person get to an answer.
joee@joee-desktop:~$ cat /etc/default/keyboard   
XKBLAYOUT="us,us,it,it,it,it"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBVARIANT=",altgr-intl,us,intl,nodeadkeys,"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="grp_led:scroll"


using the below command from terminal solved the problem for me. However I still don't understand that, doing the change from "system" does not work for me.

sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

